# "arrow" image only show half in map in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I got a problem in web development with OpenLayers 3. I want to add an arrow image by drawing a `lineString`, the image can draw and point to the direction along the `lineString` direction, but the image only displays in half, it cannot go over the the line. An excerpt from the code:

```
var start = e.feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate();
var end = e.feature.getGeometry().getLastCoordinate();

var dx = end[0] - start[0];
var dy = end[1] - start[1];
var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

var a = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(end)
});

var b = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
    anchorOrigin: 'top-left',
    offset: [0, 0],
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    rotateWithView: false,
    rotation: -rotation,
    src: '//openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/data/arrow.png',
  }))
});

var m = a.setStyle(b);
source.addFeature(a);
```

Full example replicating the problem can be seen in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/nmdem3rm/12/.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem with only part of the image being displayed was caused by you specifying value of `offset`; as per [the documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html):

> define the sub-rectangle to use from the original icon image. Default value is [0, 0].

Setting it to `[0, 0]` fixes the problem.

Another problem is that the anchor point of the image is *not* in "top-left", it's roughly in the middle of the icon. The value of `anchor` should be set to `[0.5, 0.5]`. The last problem is that the arrow head is attached to the start of the arrow, not the end.

```
var a = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(end)
});

var b = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
    anchorOrigin: 'top-left',
    offset: [0, 0],
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    rotateWithView: false,
    rotation: -rotation,
    src: '//openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/data/arrow.png',
  }))
});
```

I fixed your JSFiddle [and posted here](http://jsfiddle.net/kryger/kux7fw49/1/).

Comment: wow, thanks  kryger, it confused me for a whole day, thank you very much. I think I mixed the anchor and offset up. Could explain the meaning of both properties to me . I dont know what do anchor and offset mean, and their difference ( when i change value in them, they both change the position). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WenhuaHu did you try the linked official documentation first? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html

Comment: yes, but the explanation is too brief, i still cannot undertand (anchor, anchorOrigin, offset, offsetOrign), I am a new to Openlayers

Comment: It's a good idea to ask follow-up questions in a new question, instead of adding comments. New question is seen by far many more people than comments which you add to an individual answer so there's a greater chance of getting help.